# Wordpress custom taxonomy pagination not working

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I’m using the WP PageNavi plugin for pagination. This particular problem in not getting the taxonomy-portflio-category.php page to paginate is also a problem when WP PageNavi is turned off.

I’ve had a heck of a time getting pagination to work on the homepage and on a page template page, but I did get them to work. Here’s their code:

**page-home.php** (used as a Page template on a static front page called “Home”)

```
$paged = 1;
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged');
if ( get_query_var('page') ) $paged = get_query_var('page');
$i = 0;
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'paged' => $paged, 'posts_per_page' => 24 ) );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
// output
$i++; endwhile;
if ( function_exists( 'wp_pagenavi' ) ) {
    wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $loop ) );
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Pagination works!

**page-portfolio.php** (used as a Page template on a Page called “Work”)

```
$i = 0;
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ), 'posts_per_page' => 24 ) );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
// output
$i++; endwhile;
if ( function_exists( 'wp_pagenavi' ) ) {
    wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $loop ) );
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Pagination works!

**taxonomy-portfolio-category.php** (used as a way to display portfolio sections e.g. print, photography, etc.)

```
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
global $wp_query;
query_posts( array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'posts_per_page' => 2 ) ) );
if (have_posts()) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
// output
endwhile; endif;
if ( function_exists( 'wp_pagenavi' ) ) {
    wp_pagenavi();
}
```

Page 1 (/portfolio/interactive/) looks great! It’s definitely only posting 2 items and it calculates the correct number of pagination pages. But when you click on page 2 or 3 or 4 (/portfolio/interactive/page/2/) the site defaults to index.php and shows “Page not found”. Pagination fails!

Hopefully I can resolve this soon. I’ve seen A LOT of people with this same problem of pagination on custom taxonomy pages, but no solid solutions. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

You Need to set posts per page to 24 on the Settings -> Reading page in WP admin. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried using WP-Pagenavi but it never worked so i used the pagination from Wordpress it self, i used the twentyfourteen_paging_nav() function form Twentyfourteen becuse it has a taxonomy page, here is the code:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'twentyfourteen_paging_nav' ) ) :
function twentyfourteen_paging_nav() {
global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;

// Don't print empty markup if there's only one page.
if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages < 2 ) {
    return;
}

$paged        = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? intval( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
$pagenum_link = html_entity_decode( get_pagenum_link() );
$query_args   = array();
$url_parts    = explode( '?', $pagenum_link );

if ( isset( $url_parts[1] ) ) {
    wp_parse_str( $url_parts[1], $query_args );
}

$pagenum_link = remove_query_arg( array_keys( $query_args ), $pagenum_link );
$pagenum_link = trailingslashit( $pagenum_link ) . '%_%';

$format  = $wp_rewrite->using_index_permalinks() && ! strpos( $pagenum_link, 'index.php' ) ? 'index.php/' : '';
$format .= $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() ? user_trailingslashit( $wp_rewrite->pagination_base . '/%#%', 'paged' ) : '?paged=%#%';

// Set up paginated links.
$links = paginate_links( array(
    'base'     => $pagenum_link,
    'format'   => $format,
    'total'    => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'current'  => $paged,
    'mid_size' => 1,
    'add_args' => array_map( 'urlencode', $query_args ),
    'prev_text' => __( '&larr; Previous', 'twentyfourteen' ),
    'next_text' => __( 'Next &rarr;', 'twentyfourteen' ),
) );

if ( $links ) :

?>

<nav class="pagination-contaner" role="navigation">
    <h1 class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Posts navigation', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?></h1>
    <ul class="pagination">
        <?php echo $links; ?>
    </ul><!-- .pagination -->
</nav><!-- .navigation -->
<?php
endif;
}
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issue, it took me hours of googling! I found the solution at last.
Add the following code to functions.php in your theme folder:

```
$option_posts_per_page = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
add_action( 'init', 'my_modify_posts_per_page', 0);
function my_modify_posts_per_page() {
    add_filter( 'option_posts_per_page', 'my_option_posts_per_page' );
}
function my_option_posts_per_page( $value ) {
    global $option_posts_per_page;
    if ( is_tax( 'portfolio-category') ) {
        return 2;
    } else {
        return $option_posts_per_page;
    }
}
```

[URL for the solution](http://photodune.net/forums/thread/wordpress-custom-page-type-taxonomy-pagination/43010?page=2)

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to enable search to enable pagination

While declaring custom taxonomy you should disable search excluding.

```
exclude_from_search => false
```

This fixed my problem.

Comment: Please remember to format code with the correct method when including it in responses. The icon that you want to press is { } rather than the ".

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share following solution (add this code to `functions.php` in your theme):

```
function fix_taxonomy_pagination ( $query ) {
  // not an admin page and it is the main query
  if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()){

    if(is_tax()){
      // where 24 is number of posts per page on custom taxonomy pages
      $query->set('posts_per_page', 24);

    }
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'fix_taxonomy_pagination' );
```

[source](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/wordpress-pagination-gives-404-unless-i-set-blog-pages-show-at-most-to-1-in-reading)